# What does "kgcd" mean in abstract algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, gcd-and-lcm

I am reviewing for my abstract algebra final. 
I know that "gcd" = the greatest common divisor.
However, I am confused about what is "kgcd".

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Where did you see "kgcd"?  Could it be an integer $k$ times the greatest common divisor?

Comment: I saw it in my professor's lecture note. I am also confused about it. k times the greatest common divisor should be its meaning. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of *kgcd* being an abbreviation for something,

the way $\gcd$ stands for greatest common divisor.

Without more details, I can't be sure,

but I wonder if "kgcd" means an integer $k$ multiplied by the $\gcd$,

such as in the statement $\gcd(ka,kb)=k\gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think this should be what my professor means.

Answer (score 1):

kgcd is not an acronym as far as I know. It simply means gcd multiplied by some number k.

As an example, and I suspect in the case of abstract algebra you'd get kgcd from:

gcd(kx,ky) = kgcd(x,y)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!